# Is generic record key possible?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to return a Record with a generic key? Typing allows it, but implementation seems not possible.

```js
function foo<K extends string>(key: K): Record<K, string> {
    return {
        [key]: "foo"
    }
}
```

Error:

> `Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, string>'.(2322)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to assert that your returned object is of the right type.

```
function foo<K extends string>(key: K): Record<K, string> {
    return {
        [key]: "foo"
    } as Record<K, string>
}
```

The reason that this is necessary is because typescript acknowledges the possibility that the type `K` can be broader than just the literal string `key` (`K` could be `string` or union of string literals).  If that's the case then your returned object would not actually fulfill the return type because it would not have a value for every key `K`.

It is currently not possible to state that a generic must be a single literal string, so some finessing with `as` is required.

Comment: It's fun to go down this particular rabbit hole, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1kOm) maybe.  This is something they considered, mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030) (as the `Unionize` type) but I guess it never made it anywhere.